# I want to assign the each 6 elements of tt[ ] to the Monday to Friday and last 4 elements to the saturday

Tags: python-3.x, list

tt=[] is the list which have a 34 elements, I want function to assign each 6 element to the of the list to Monday to friday, and last 4 elements to satuday.

```
tt=["c","e","ae","be","f","g","i","ce","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","jh","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","kd","ll","dfd","dgdfg"]
count=1

def creatFirst():
    for i in tt:
        if len(a) <= 6:       
            if count>=0 and count <7:
                a.append("i")
                count+=1
                a.append(i)

    return a

monday=creatFirst()
tuesday=creatFirst()
wednesday=creatFirst()
thursday=creatFirst()
friday=creatFirst()
saturday=creatFirst()
print(monday)
print(tuesday)
print(wednesday)
print(thursday)
print(friday)
print(saturday)

#output should look like this

monday["c","e","ae","be","f","g"]
Tuesday["i","ce","k","l","m","n"]
Wednesday["o","p","q","r","s","t"]
Thursday["u","v","w","x","y","z"]
friday["jh","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg"]
saturday["kd","ll","dfd","dgdfg"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you want, if not add context to your question but why not just do:

```
tt = ["c","e","lab","lab1","f","g","i","seminar","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","jh","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","kd","ll","dfd","dgdfg"]

monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday = [], [], [], [], [], []
days = [monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday]

for i, day in enumerate(days):
    day += tt[i * 6: (i+1) * 6]

for day in days:
    print(day)
```

```
['c', 'e', 'lab', 'lab1', 'f', 'g']
['i', 'seminar', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
['o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
['jh', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg']
['kd', 'll', 'dfd', 'dgdfg']
```